# How to embed a Facebook Analytics report?

Tags: facebook, facebook-analytics

Is it possible to embed a Facebook Analytics report on a website?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Facebook Analytics does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a 3rd party web app to be able to embed FB insights into any webpage. I've tested some apps like dashthis, octoboard, and supermetrics. So far, Octoboard is far way easier and simpler to integrate with many visual graphs alternative/choices.